# Null and Booleans operator

Tags: javascript, null, expression, boolean-expression

I'm really new at programming and although I understand the concepts I have some trouble putting them in practice. For example I understood the concept of null and undefined values... and booleans operators.. all good!!! but when it comes to simple exercise I get stuck. 
For example I got this :

Write an expression that evaluates x, so long as x is not null; if x is null, the expression should evaluate to 100. x is equal to null when no value has been assigned to it (e.g. var x;), but you could also assign it the value of null (var x = null;). Test your expression for several different values of x, including null - does it behave like you expect?

This is what I did:

```
var x ; 

myExpression = (x - 50 + 20 + 30);

if (x === null) {
    myExpression === true;
}
else if (x !== null) {
    myExpression === 50;
}
```

It doesn't look right to me at all , and I know it's not. I think my real problem is understanding the problem itself. Can you please try to help me understanding it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: When you want to assign a value to myExpression, you should use = instead of the comparison operator ===. For example: myExpression = 50;  That is not the only problem in your code though... :-)

Comment: *"x is equal to null when no value has been assigned to it (e.g. var x;)"* - That's not correct: `x` would have the value `undefined`, which is not the same as `null`. But `null==undefined` with double equals sign does evaluate as `true`. Yet `null===undefined` with triple equals sign evaluates as `false`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan I was using repl.it and it would't recognise the expression if I put = instead of === . Yeah I knew there were lots of problem in it... Thanks though to everyone ..very helpful!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are making this too hard.   The expression:

```
((x == null) ? 100 : x)
```

A sample use:

```
y =  ((x == null) ? 100 : x);
```

Your assignment said:

> Write an expression that evaluates x, so long as x is not null; if x is null, the expression should evaluate to 100.

An expression is something which evaluates to a value.  The number `6` is an expression.  A variable, like `x` is an expression.  More complicated expressions can be built using mathematical operators, for example `6 + x` and so on.

The *ternary* (or "question mark") operator is a very powerful tool for building expressions.

condition ? value1 : value2

this works like something like a "mini-function":

```
function questionmark ( condition ) {
       if ((condition) != 0) {
           return value1;
       } else {
           return value2;
       }
}
```

So:

```
(x == null) ? 100 : x
```

evaluates to 100 if `x` is `null` and the value of `x` otherwise.

Think of this expression as using 100 as the default value for something -- for example, we are going to do something `x` times, but if they haven't told us `x` we'll do it 100 times.

You should see that

```
(x != null) ? x : 100
```

is an equivalent expression.

In JavaScript there are more compact ("trickier") ways to write this kind of expression. I include them here just so you might recognize them if you see them in code:

```
(x ? x : 100)

(x || 100)
```

Comment: OP is "really new at programming". Do you expect them to understand your code without explanation?

Comment: what you did is basically making the expression null true, through a ternary operator.. isn't it?